# play video from external database in android?

Tags: android, database, video

I'd like to know how I can call a video from an external server database and play it in android? any helpful tutorials?
another question, when I play my video in emulator is it normal that it gives me a low quality and plays very slow..like moving in slow motion?

Answer (score 0):

Emulators not responded quickly  while you are playing video.I hope you understand that.